# Paypal JS SDK Automatically Closes in Sandbox JSP Servlet Web Application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, paypal-sandbox, content-security-policy

I'm testing a sandbox PayPal for a learning project in the JSP servlet. I'm using NetBeans IDE with the glassfish server and XAMPP for the database. The following code runs the Paypal payment buttons, but when I click the payment button Paypal window pops up and crashes suddenly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Purchase</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AbdB49QXlBjEzeWDSu1ws2QrNR3FpcpcGPOif2a7XvK6sDKMkD8ijA2q0c5CdI-w2cUHlKTj_LLyn5cu&locale=en_US" data-csp-nonce="xxx"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    
    <script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions){
                return actions.order.create({
                    purcchase_units: [{
                            amount:{
                                value: '295'
                            }
                    }]
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container')
    </script>
</body>
```

The above code is in the index.jsp file and the auto close issue persists. According to what I found online it could be due to my localhost is HTTP and Paypal blocking non-https Requests. If so, please help me to set up HTTPS on my server. Or if the issue is something else hope to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the browser console explains the problem

> Uncaught Error: a.purchase_units is undefined

Comment: Oh, the issues seems to be with my code. I had accidentally used (typo) purcchase_units instead of purchase_units.  It worked when this is fixed.